# How to measure the inertia of an object using a motor

Tags: mechanical-engineering, measurements, prototyping

first time on this board even if I've been lurking for a while.

I'm a tennis racquet technician and, for the sake of saving some money and just for the fun of it, I'm trying to build a machine that could measure the inertial properties of a racquet in a more efficient way than the typical pendulum setup.

Here is a picture of the typical commercially available (and overly expensive) machines:
[image]

I figure that an accelerometer ans gyroscope would do ths trick measuring the angular acceleration of the baseline setup (shaft and clamping device) and a motor that could provide data of torque variation due to increased inertia of the added racquet for a given angle should do the trick. Im having trouble finding such a motor or another sensor that could perform thia task.

Any suggestions or pointers here?

Thank you very much!

Claudio